# C program to count occurrences of a word in file

Tags: c

I write a program to count all occurrences of all words in a text file in c.I give a loop to go through each word and check it against every other word in the file but it fails

```
void CountAllOccurren(char * file)
{
char words[100];
int len = strlen(file);
char f[len];//name file
char word[100];
int i,count;
for( i = 0; i < len;i++)
{
    f[i] = file[i];
}
f[len] = '\0';
FILE* file_ptr = fopen(f, "r");
// Read the file
int c;
while(fscanf(file_ptr, "%s", word) != EOF){

    while (fgets(words,100,file_ptr))
    {
        //i want to count occurrences of a word but failed
         printf("%s\n",word);
        
    }
    
    
}
fclose(file_ptr);  
}
```

1. input: file content

> i want to help to want want.

2. output: Terminal

> i:1 - want:3 - to:2 - help:1

Comment: `f[len] = '\0';` is off to a bad start, writing to a byte that is beyond the end of the array... Why are you attempting to make a copy of the filename to begin with? And, it helps to verify that `fopen()` didn't fail, passed the name, perhaps, of a non-existent file...

Comment: You will need to define a structure containing a word and the number of occurrences of the word, and you will need a collection of that structure type (array, list, …).  As you identify each word in the file, you either increment the count if the word has been seen before, or you add the word with a count of one if it is a new word.  At the end, you iterate over the structure to print the words with their counts.  That could be a list or a dynamically allocated array of structures.  You'll need to make copies of the word when adding them to the structure.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where `fgets` adds an unnecessary complication. Just do something like: `char word[1000]; int r=scanf("%999s", word); /* check r */`

Comment: Why are you copying the string `file`?  You don't need to. `FILE* file_ptr = fopen(file, "r");` does what you need.

Comment: _"i want to count occurrences of a word but failed"_  Have you already written code you can share?  Or what failed?   What you need:  an array of strings (containing the unique words you find) and an array of counts (the count of each unique word).

Comment: As already mentions, you don't need to copy `file`. Even if you had to, why would you invent your own `strcpy` replacement instead of just using the existing C standard library function?